# Asyncio Return future pending for result

Tags: xml, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am using a package called [IBSYNC](https://github.com/erdewit/ib_insync) to request data from Interactive Broker. Basically, the code will return a XML file.

The code is running and I can see the XML has been returned (printed on the broker's console). However, when I  use .result(), it returns Future pending.

How can I get the XML instead?

```
async def ReportsFinStatements(symbol, exchange, currency, primary):
    stock = Stock(symbol, exchange, currency, primaryExchange= primary)
    #ib.qualifyContractsAsync(stock)
    assert await ib.reqContractDetailsAsync(stock)
    data = ib.reqFundamentalDataAsync(contract=stock, reportType='ReportsFinStatements')
    return data

async def main():
    group1 = loop.create_task(ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'))
    group2 = loop.create_task(ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'))
    group3 = loop.create_task(ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'))
    await asyncio.wait([group1, group2, group3])
    return group1, group2, group3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        d1, d2, d3 = loop.run_until_complete(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print('logging')
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

d1 is `<Task finished coro=<ReportsFinStatements() done, defined at <ipython-input-4-4a5ceba20b3a>:1> result=<Future pending>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues:

- You need to `await` the call to `reqFundamentalDataAsync`. This is why you're getting a pending future, it's the return value of `reqFundamentalDataAsync` (when not awaited) and therefore of your `ReportsFinStatements`.
- You need to use `asyncio.gather()` instead of `asyncio.wait()`, in which case you won't need to call `result()` on the returned values. (Once the previous point is implemented, you *could* use `asyncio.wait()` as you tried, and call `result()` on the tasks, but `asyncio.gather()` is designed so you don't have to do that.)

Finally, you don't need to use `create_task` explicitly, both `asyncio.gather` and `asyncio.wait` to it for you automatically when passed coroutine objects. For example, you can write `main` like this:

```py
async def main():
    return await asyncio.gather(
        ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'),
        ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'),
        ReportsFinStatements('PIH', 'SMART', 'USD', 'NASDAQ'))
```